# Google Maps API multiple times on this page - Ruby on Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm having a lot of problems when it comes to reloading a view with a Google map. When I refresh (F5) or navigate directly via URL, the map loads perfectly, the problem is when I use a link on the same view, for example:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Alerta Ciudadana</a>
```

or

```
<%= link_to root_path %>
```

I've already searched on stackoverflow and countless google topics. But I can't get a solution. Here's a screenshot of the broswer console. 
[image: error]

Hope someone can help out.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a JS event is getting triggered, and that trigger adds the Maps API each time it is called?

Comment: agree with steel. maybe the google maps js is loaded not in the head tag of your html but in the body tag and you may be using turbolinks.

Comment: I fixed it, but I´m not proud of the solution. I just removed //= require turbolinks on my application.js file. I don't want to get rid of turbolinks, but it's the only solution I've found. Any thoughts